# How to programmatically delete an image style in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Need help trying to figure out how to programmatically delete an image style in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$image_style = image_style_load('IMAGE_STYLE');
image_style_delete($image_style);
```

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_delete/7

You may need to flush the image style cache before it'll let you delete it. You can do that with:

```
image_style_flush($image_style);
```

For more info, see:

1. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_flush/7
2. http://www.benmarshall.me/programmatically-create-delete-image-styles-drupal/

Comment: Note* The code in image_style_delete() automatically calls an image_style_flush(). @see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_delete/7

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
// Load the style.
$style = image_style_load('styleName');
// Flush images associated with the style.
image_style_flush($style);
// Delete the style.
image_style_delete($style);
?>
```

This will not work on the default styles. It is recommended to not remove them, since a number of Drupal modules depends on it.

**Update:**

If you've modified the default styles (Thumbnail, Medium, Large), you cannot delete them. Instead, you can just revert them back to their original settings, like this.

```
<?php
// Load the style.
$style = image_style_load('styleName');
// Flush images associated with the style.
image_style_flush($style);
// Revert the style.
image_default_style_revert($style);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment about being best not to remove them. Is there a way to disable the default ones?

Comment: Also, timofey, you said "If you've modified the default styles". How exactly do I modify the default styles? I would want to remove them but since that can't be done at least let me change the label on each one. Thanks